# updating multiple document at once

Tags: mongoose

I have an array that contains objects of users, like below.

```
[
  {id: 122, name: 'Jone', addr: '11111aaaa'},
  {id: 12, name: 'Jane', addr: 'spring field'},
  {id: 14, name: 'Joe', addr: 'awesome street'},
]
```

When each user is saved to a separated document, is there any way that I can update the user's address at once? Or do I just have to do the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multi update ?

```
db.collection.update({
  name: {
    $in: [
      "Jone",
      "Jane"
    ]
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    addr: "somewhere"
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/azsXUVFemgR)